# Ruby check if method chaining is valud

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chain

Suppose I have an `Active Record` class.

If I have:

Houses, which has many People, who have many Dogs, who have many Collars.

I will not do the schema definitions as they are trivial.

Now I want from a page where I have a house object to iterate through all the collars in that house.

So:

```
for c in house.people.dogs.collars do
  puts c
end
```

If there are no people in a house then I will get an `undefined method` error when the chain gets to `people.dogs`.

I can get around this in two ways. I can enclose the whole thing in a nest of if statements, checking one level at a time and only executing the above code if I have first verified all the parts of the chain. I also could use `begin` and `rescue`.

My question is:

Is there another way to do this?  Some method which would allow me to do something like:

```
for c in foo(house.people.dogs.collars) do
  puts c
end
```

with no other code. Foo would check if the chain is valid, then execute it, otherwise it would silently do nothing. If there is no existing best way to do this, I will just make a function myself and have it return a hash or array as an ensure.

Comment: In Rails: `house.people.try(:dogs).try(:collars)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is not correct. Because `house.people` would return an array. And you cannot call `dogs` on that array. You will have to call `dogs` on each person in the array.

The following would work for both cases, if there are elements in the association or if there aren't:

```
house.people.flat_map(&:dogs).flat_map(&:collars)
```

You might want to clean this up with [has_many through associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) or have a method on `house` that encapsulates that logic.

Furthermore it is worth it to mention that you will experience a terrible performance, because each step in the chain would result in multiple calls to the database. Depending on the size of your database I would consider to write specialized scopes with database joins.

Comment: Thanks, I had meant and as far as I can see have written that the problem will occur when I try and access dogs.  I understand that people would return an array and that an array would have no method 'dogs'.  I will take a look at this as well as the reply.  Yes :through relations would work as well, I have used them for various things.  My question was simply because often there is an incredibly terse way to do various things in ruby, and I wondered if such a thing existed here.